# JxBrowser does not launch from another class

Tags: jxbrowser

I have a problem that I cannot launch my JxBrowser from another class but it works fine on its own class. I will give the code for the internet browser class here

```
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
    import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class InternetBrowser 
    {
       //properties
       Browser browser;
       BrowserView browserView;
       JFrame frame;

       //constructor
       public InternetBrowser()
       {
           browser = new Browser();
           browserView = new BrowserView(browser);
           frame = new JFrame();



       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.add(browserView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
           frame.setSize(500, 500);
           frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           frame.setVisible(true);
        browser.loadURL("https://www.youtube.com/embed/bO7yYDIOuXo");

     }

     public static void main( String [] args )
     {
         InternetBrowser browser = new InternetBrowser();
     }

}
```

The error that I get is

Class StartIPCTask is implemented in both /private/var/folders/cs/1z68c1xs2q3crwrwm__fx_t80000gn/T/jxmaps-chromium-49.0.2623.110.unknown/data/Temp/libjxmaps-common64-397f2f15-9ac5-4806-91f6-88c8aaa29714.dylib (0x1288d5630) and /private/var/folders/cs/1z68c1xs2q3crwrwm__fx_t80000gn/T/browsercore-64.0.3282.24.6.21/data/Temp/libbrowsercore-common64-01e73e7f-2b85-4bd3-ac76-05d908fa4928.dylib (0x16b2576c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

I need to define which one of the directories that the class should use but I do not know how. I am using the latest version of Netbeans. Also at the top of the class that im trying to construct a browser, the imports are highlighted as "unused import". Thank you for your help!

Comment: It appears that the second directory that it shows is necessary for OSX. How can I make the program choose one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this is a bug seen in OSX.. The program works without any problem in windows computers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this warning doesn't affect the program, so you can just ignore it. If you don't want to receive it at all, then please try using the `jxbrowser.jni.singleton.fix=false` VM parameter.